# calculate correlation of broken time series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

Is it statistically correct to calculate correlations between two broken time series?

For example,

```
x <- seq(from = 1, to = 3000, by = 1) + 10 + rnorm(3000, sd = 5) 
y <- seq(from = 1, to = 3000, by = 1) + 10 + rnorm(3000, sd = 12) 

blockA1 <- c(1:500, 600:900)
blockB1 <- c(501:599, 901:2299)
blockA2 <- c(2300:2700,2901:3000)
blockB2 <- c(2701:2900)

blockA <- c(blockA1,blockA2)
blockB <- c(blockB1,blockB2)

cor(x[blockA], y[blockA])
```

Is this a valid way to compute correlations?

EDIT: For example, let's say I collected heart rate data continuously on day 1 (x) and day 2 (y). blockA are rest periods and blockB are activity periods.
By splitting the data into rest/activity blocks, I'm breaking the time series. Can I really assume that blockA1 + blockA2 (the entire rest period for day 1) is equivalent to measuring blockA continuously?

Comment: Mathematically, everything is ok.  But (1) what is the intended role of `blockB` in your example and (2) what do you really mean by "valid" or "statistically correct"?  That is, how do you hope to interpret the result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @whuber. I would like to compute correlations for `blockB` as well, and then compare the result with that of `blockA`.
By "statistically correct" I'm simply concerned that by splitting the time series like I did in my example, I will get biased estimates, since the original time series are continuous, not broken.

Comment: For example, let's say I collected heart rate data continuously on day 1 (x) and day 2(y). blockA are rest periods and blockB activity. I would think that breaking the time series like in the example would not reflect true rest or activity periods because their values could partly depend on earlier blocks, so my correlation estimates might be slightly erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally correct to do so. If you want an other method to compute a temporal trend, you can also have a look at the [Mann-Kendall](https://wikitia.com/wiki/Mann-Kendall_trend_test) test. In R you have several packages proposing this (*e.g.* package [trend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trend/trend.pdf), package [Kendall](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Kendall/Kendall.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with an example why I would be interested in splitting the data into blocks. Does Mann-Kendall (or any test for that matter) have a way to correct for breaking the time series? It's just that it looks to me that I'll get biased estimates, given that I have effectively created an "artificial" time series by joining, for example, blockA1 with blockA2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct but keep in mind that why are blocking the series.One realistic reason is that there exists heteroscedasticity on your data in specific time periods. By excluding them (blocking), and keeping only the time period that $\sigma^2$ is stationary or your data are homoskedastic will give you the opportunity to nicely model them with arch or garch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with an example when blocking would be required. As I mention in my comment below, it seems to me that I'm bound to get biased estimates since I'm artificially creating time series (eg by joining blockA1 with blockA2). Is this not the case?